# how to angular add label to radiobutton created with *ngFor

Tags: html, label, ngfor

```
<form *ngFor="let i of addresss">
  <label style="display: block;">
    <div class="editing">
      <a (click)="editLocation(i.id)">edit</a>
      <a (click)="deleteLocation(i.id)">delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-3 border mb-3">
      <span class="d-block text-primary h6 text-uppercase">
        <input type="radio" name="action">{{i.title}}</span>
      <p class="mb-0" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">{{i.address}} , {{i.city}} , Near {{i.landmark1}} , {{i.landmark2}} , {{i.state}}</p>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

when i click on the label it not perform like radio button.. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a form for each address. You can fix it by wrapping your addresses with a div.

Example:

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let i of addresss">
        <label style="display: block;">
            <div class="editing">
                <a (click)="editLocation(i.id)">edit</a>
                <a (click)="deleteLocation(i.id)">delete</a>
            </div>
            <div class="p-3 border mb-3">
                <span class="d-block text-primary h6 text-uppercase">                             
                            <input type="radio" name="action">{{i.title}}</span>
                <p class="mb-0" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">{{i.address}} , {{i.city}} , Near {{i.landmark1}} , {{i.landmark2}} , {{i.state}}</p>
            </div>
        </label>
     </div>
</form>
```